# How to iterate a tensorflow.train.Example or train.Feature object to get a python list?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensorflow.train.Feature object which I need to traverse and make a numpy array out of it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
int_feature = tf.train.Feature(
    int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
float_feature = tf.train.Feature(
    float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[1., 2., 3., 4.]))

example = tf.train.Example(
    features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'my_ints': int_feature,
        'my_floats': float_feature
    }))
```

How can I convert it to a numpy array or a python list?

Expected output:

```
[[1, 1.], [2, 2.], [3, 3.], [4, 4.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the answer after some trial and error.

```
arr_1 = np.array(example.features.feature['my_ints'].int64_list.value).reshape(1, -1)
arr_2 = np.array(example.features.feature['my_floats'].float_list.value).reshape(1, -1)
print(arr_1)
print(arr_2)
np.stack([arr_1, arr_2], axis = 1)
```

Comment: If you want to use tensorflow-only operations, you can use [`tf.io.parse_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_example)